# First order linear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I would like to solve the following *first order non-homogenous* recurrence relation
$$
\left(n^2+n-1\right) y_{n+1}-(n-2)\,n\,y_n=\frac{1}{256} \left(25 n^3+150 n^2-173 n+32\right)\,.
$$

It is a simple exercise to solve the associated *homogenous* recurrence relation
$$
\left(n^2+n-1\right)\,y^H_{n+1}-(n-2)\,n\,y^H_n=0\,,
$$
which yields
$$
y^H_n = C_1\,\frac{\Gamma (n-2) \Gamma (n)}{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\,,
$$
where $C_1$ is a constant and $\Gamma$ is a gamma function.

I tried to use ***telescoping*** to solve for $y_n$. In order to do this I set
$$
y_n = y_n^H+y_n^H z_n
$$
which gives for $z_n$
$$
z_{n}-z_{n-1}=\frac{\left(25 n^3+75 n^2-398 n+330\right)}{256} \frac{\Gamma \left(n-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n-2) \Gamma (n)}\,.
$$
However, I was not able to find a closed form for
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\left(25 k^3+75 k^2-398 k+330\right)}{256} \frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k-2) \Gamma (k)}.
$$

Any other ideas?

Comment: What makes you think this _has_ a neat closed form? Trying to use [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) gives a truly horrendous ODE: 

$$
x^3 Y'' - 2x^2 Y' + Y + c_0 = \frac{165 x^3 - 271 x^2 + 47 x - 16}{128 (1-x)^4}
$$

(where $c_0$ is a parameter) which [sage](https://sagemath.org) doesn't know how to solve. Here $Y(x) = \sum_n y_n x^n$. The singularities of $Y$ can give good asymptotic estimates for the $y_n$s, and $Y$ has a particularly nice closed form we can compute a closed form for the $y_n$ from this... Unfortunately, this _doesn't_.

Comment: Wolframalpha can "solve" this ODE (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3+Y%27%27+-+2x%5E2+Y%27+%2B+Y%3D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B128%7D+%5Cfrac%7B165+x%5E3+-+271+x%5E2+%2B+47+x+-+16%7D%7Bx%5E4+-+4x%5E3+%2B+6x%5E2+-+4x+%2B+1%7D)) but I'm not sure how to taylor expand it and check my work. Also the solution is hideous (see the link) and I wouldn't know how to manipulate it into a form that lets us control even the asymptotics of $y_n$. To me this is a sign that there may not be a great way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;y_n=u_n+v_n,\;$ where
$$v_n=\dfrac{5n^2+35n-56}{256},\quad (n^2+n-1)v_{n+1}-(n-2)nv_n = \dfrac{25n^2+150n^2-173n+16}{256}.\tag1$$
Then
$$(n^2+n-1)u_{n+1}-(n-2)nu_n = \dfrac1{16}.\tag2$$

As it was shown in the OP, solution of the homogeneous recurrence relation is
$$u^\,_H=\dfrac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n-2)}{\Gamma(n+\varphi)\Gamma(n-\varphi+1)},\tag3$$
where $\;\varphi=\dfrac{\sqrt5+1}2\;$ is the golden ratio.

Substitution $\;u=u^\,_H w\;$ leads to the equation
$$w_{n+1}-w_n = \dfrac{\Gamma(n+\varphi)\Gamma(n-\varphi+1)}{16\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n-1)}.\tag4$$

Therefore,
$$y_n=C\,\dfrac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n-2)}{\Gamma(n+\varphi)\Gamma(n-\varphi+1)}+\dfrac{5n^2+35n-56}{256}+\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n-1}
\dfrac{\Gamma(k+\varphi)\Gamma(k-\varphi+1)}{16\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k-1)},\tag5$$
where the parameters $\;C,m\;$ should be defined from addition conditions.

Presentation $(5)$ is not a closed form, but it looks as the maximum of possible.